# How do I generate these sequences based on the shown below parameters

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

Suppose I have a finite list of real number pairs $(\nu_k, i_k)$ with $k = 1, \ldots, K$. Then I computed $\nu_0$ and $i_0$ as some kind of average of the numbers and similarly $\Delta \nu$ and $\Delta i$ as some kind of average jumping distance between the numbers in the sequence.

Now for a positive integer $N > 0$ I shall now construct the following two finite sequences:

$$\{v_0 - N\cdot\Delta v, \ldots, v_0 - \Delta v, v_0+\Delta v,\ldots,v_0+N\cdot\Delta v\}\\
  \{i_0 - N\cdot\Delta i, \ldots, i_0 - \Delta i, i_0+\Delta i,\ldots,i_0+N\cdot\Delta i\}
$$

I have been told they should both be of length $2N$. I do not understand why.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation
$$\{\nu_0 - N\cdot\Delta \nu, \ldots, \nu_0 - \Delta \nu, \nu_0+\Delta \nu,\ldots,\nu_0+N\cdot\Delta \nu\}$$

means
$$\begin{align*}
    \{&\nu_0 - N\cdot\Delta \nu,\\
      &\nu_0 - (N-1)\Delta \nu,\\
      &\nu_0 - (N-2)\Delta \nu,\\
      &\nu_0 - (N-3)\Delta \nu,\\
      &\ldots,\\
      &\nu_0 - (N-(N-1))\Delta \nu = \nu_0 - \Delta \nu,\\
      &\nu_0 + \Delta \nu,\\
      &\nu_0 + 2\Delta \nu,\\
      &\ldots\\
      &\nu_0 + (N-2)\Delta \nu\\
      &\nu_0 + (N-1)\Delta \nu\\
      &\nu_0 + N\Delta \nu\}.
  \end{align*}
$$
This set should exactly contain $2N$ elements if I counted correctly.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense to me